# URL with user name in Joomla 3.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, redirect

I am looking for solution to show the url with username. I am using Joomla 3.3.0 stable version.

Ex. site_url/userp-username

I tried to solve this using .htaccess with following rules that I have used for my core PHP websites.

```
RewriteRule ^userp-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ site_url/index.php?option ... er_name=$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I hit the url for example http://sitename.com/userp-vishal07 it execute the code that I want to call for this url and it shows the results correctly. But url does not remain as it is and turn into http://vicciivital.com/index.php/en/component/users/profile?layout=view_profile&user_name=vishal07

I am not able to understand how the Joomla redirect works. Please correct me if I am doing any mistakes here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! On the site it is discouraged to add signatures and things like "thanks in advance!" to questions. It just adds noise, the site really strives to be black and white - question and answer. The votes from users do all the talking about good and bad - and things like thank you's for good answers :)

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I have never understood the com_users router does not route any profiles except the users own profile.

```
/**
 * Method to get a route configuration for the profile view.
 *
 * @return  mixed   Integer menu id on success, null on failure.
 * @since   1.6
 */
public static function getProfileRoute()
{
    // Get the items.
    $items  = self::getItems();
    $itemid = null;

    // Search for a suitable menu id.
    //Menu link can only go to users own profile.

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        if (isset($item->query['view']) && $item->query['view'] === 'profile')
        {
            $itemid = $item->id;
            break;
        }

    }
    return $itemid;
}
```

What you would need to do is extend this method to handle everyone's profiles.   Just make sure to deal with the situation that there is a content item or tag with the same alias as the alias for the user.

In general the easiest workaround is to use com_contact as a profile instead.  Turning on the contact creator plugin will create contacts for your new users automatically and contact can display anything from a profile plugin. Also it can display articles by the user and then you can also add plugins for other things if you want.   To me it always works a lot better then messing with the com_users profile.